# Regular expression of validating text which contains certain special characters on condition

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression which will validate a text. Conditions are as follows:

1. Must contain at least one alphanumeric character [A-Za-z0-9]
2. Can contain allowed special character like [@#]. This is optional.
3. No other characters are allowed other than the above mentioned chars[includes @ and #].
4. Text length should be less than 8.

**valid text:** A, A@, @A, A@a@, @@@a etc

**invalid text :** @, @#, a:**, A@%, AAAAAAAAA(9 characters) etc

I have tried the below regex but it is partly working:

**(?=.*[\w])(?=.*[@#])?.*{0,8}**

Comment: Try regexr.com , it lets you try out different regex on sample text in real time and has a handy regex cheatsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#]{0,8}$
```

Try this.See [demo.](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/52)

The `lookahead` will make sure there is atleast `one` character.

Comment: ^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#]{1,7}$  <- it is supposed to have less than 8 characters, and contain at least 1 alpha numeric

Comment: @SQL.injection the lookahead will make sure there is atleast one character

Comment: then `{0,8}` is unnecessary.

Comment: yep, your regex is same as mine except i put `1`, but you put `0` /. `{1,8}`, won't create any problem.

Comment: @vks matches method won't need anchors.

Comment: difference what difference? with or without anchors in matches method won't create any problem.

Comment: may i know why op used a regex without anchors?

Comment: @AvinashRaj guess you should call OP

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex in `matches` method.

```
"(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#]{1,8}"
```

`(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])` asserts that the string must contain atleast one letter or digit , so there must be a single character present in the match. That's why i defined `[A-Za-z0-9@#]{1,8}` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9@#]{0,8}`

```
String[] check = {"A", "A@", "@A", "A@a@", "@@@a", "@", "@#", "a:**", "A@%", "AAAAAAAAA"};
for(String i: check)
{

    System.out.println(i.matches("(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#]{1,8}"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Za-z0-9])[@#A-Za-z0-9]{1,8}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "aaaaaaa";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#]{1,7}"));
}
```

O/P :
true